# ButtonDownFcn for a patch with another patch on top

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a bunch of patches plotted in MATLAB, each with a `buttonDownFcn` specified.  Some of them have additional semi-transparent patches on top of them.  This is preventing the the callbacks from working.  I tried setting `hittest` to "off" on the top layer patches, but it's not helping. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be to set the `pickableParts` property to 'none' on objects that you don't want to block things underneath.